# When Getting Data from the API and how Saving it Into Sharepreference?

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart, sharedpreferences

```
-->    JSON Response
```

{
"data": {
"CityName": null,
"DOB": "7/07/2022",
"DeviceType": "0",
"Email": "test@gmail.com",
"MobileNo": "1234567891",
"ProfileImage": "",
"UserID": "1",
"UserName": "xyz",
"UserType": "3"
},
"message": "Successfully login",
"status": 200
}

```
  --->  API SERVICE

                  
 Future<Loginmodel?> login() async {
if (passwordController.text.isNotEmpty && nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        'XYZ',
      ),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: (jsonEncode({
        'UserName': nameController.text,
        'Password': passwordController.text,
        'DeviceToken': '',
        'DeviceType': ''
      })));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print(data);

    print(data['data']['UserID'].toString());

    if (data['data']['UserID'] == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invaild Credentials")));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homescreen()));

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Succesfully Credentials")));
    }

    // await Storage.write(key: "token", value: output["token"]);
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Black Field Not Allowed")));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use hive. Here is an article with proper guide to implement that in Hive. https://mukhtharcm.com/hive-custom-objects/

Answer (score 0):

You'll could also use [SQLlite](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) as SharedPreferances doesn't support objects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SharedPrefernces only for primitive data not objects i advice you to use sqlite if you re familiar with sql database or Hive for NoSql

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `String`: encode data when writing and decode when reading. Something like this could work:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await prefs.setString('user', jsonEncode(data['data']));

final user = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('user'));
```

Comment: when I use it , In My Api Request ?

Comment: For example. There aren't really any restrictions on where to use it.

Comment: Suppose I Use Of User ID , In MY Any Other Page So , How Can I Use It Using  SharedPreferences.?